# Error: React Refresh runtime should not be included in the production builds

Tags: react-native

Running React Native 62.2 on Android Pixel 3 XL simulator AVD 29

[image: Running React Native 62.2 on Android Pixel 3 XL simulator AVD 29]

Comment: Did you find out why .. Does it happens with other emulator (API 28 , or 30)

Answer (score 1):

For Thoose Who Are trying to run a production build. spent a few days on this.
but these are the steps I did.

1. yarn start -- --reset-cache
2. yarn start
3. To open developer menu press "d" ----  press d.
4. disable - fast reloading.
5. Go into settings and disable JS DEV MODE
6. yarn start -- --reset-cache
7. run the yarn or npm command to start your production build

Answer (score 1):

I set NODE_ENV=development, then it will worked for me. It's seem this bug occur because it automatically use production libraries instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you require runtime from that thing like

```
import runtime from "react-refresh/runtime"
```

It looks totally harmless as most probably you are injecting it conditionally BUT that thing complains about requiring it so you are looking for something like

```
 const startApplication= async () => {
    if (
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
    ) {
        const runtime = await import('react-refresh/runtime');
        runtime.injectIntoGlobalHook(window);
        window.$RefreshReg$ = () => {};
        window.$RefreshSig$ = () => (type) => type;
    }
//React boostrap logic
    boostrapAppmethod();

};
startApplication();
```